# Keyboard media keys for volume control buttons stop responding after connecting bluetooth headset

Tags: audio, keyboard, windows-11, volume-mixer

I have a keyboard with system-wide volume control keys. It works fine on Windows 11 with a Realtek wired headset. However, when I connect my Sony WH-1000XM4 Bluetooth headset, which becomes the default media output, the volume control keys stop responding. They start working again with the Realtek wired headset after the Bluetooth headset is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

In case the volume keys become unresponsive, I've found a solution by restarting the 'Windows Audio' service after connecting the Bluetooth headset. This can be achieved through the Windows services GUI, but I personally prefer the command line equivalent, which needs to be executed as an administrator:

```
powershell -command "Restart-Service audiosrv -Force"
```

For convenience, I've bundled the command into a CMD file with a short name I can easily remember and run from shell.